# Decomposition of $H^n(G,M)$ for $G$ finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have a question that I think it comes down to an algebra question, its probably something that I am missing but here it goes , we know that if $G$ is finite then $H^n(G,M)$ is annihilated by $G$ for all $n>0$, now in the book that i am reading, cohomology of groups by brown, the author then says that $H^n(G,M) = \oplus_{p}H^n(G,M)_{(p)}$ where $p$ ranges over the primes dividing $|G|$ and $H^n(G,M)_{(p)}$ is the p-primary component of $H^n(G,M)$. Now is this a general algebra fact that I forgot , or is there something more to it that uses cohomology and such ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a general algebra fact : take any abelian group $A$, and assume $n$ kills it.

Write $n= p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_n^{\alpha_n}$ with the $p_i$'s distinct primes. Then $A= \bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_{(p_i)}$.

One way to prove this is using the chinese remained theorem. Note that $A_{(p_i)} = \hom(\mathbb Z/p_i^{\alpha_i}, A)$, so $A=\hom(\mathbb Z/n,A) = \hom(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb Z/p_i^{\alpha_i},A) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \hom(\mathbb Z/p_i^{\alpha_i}, A) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_{(p_i)}$

I've cheated a bit here because I used "$=$" instead of "isomorphic to", but in fact the reason I did this is the reason why cheating works here : all the isomorphisms are the natural ones, that is, induced by evaluation at $1$, and so they are all coherent; in particular, if we replace all "$=$"'s above by "$\cong$"'s, you get maps $A_{(p_i)}\to A$ which are precisely the inclusions, so in fact the "$=$"'s are justified.

Of course you can also directly use Bezout's theorem on the $p_i$'s, but it's essentially reproving the CRT.